# How to test default props functions is attached to component or not ? | React | Jest | Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How can we write the test to check defaultProps function in this case (
 `handleChange: () => {},handleBlur: () => {},handleSubmit: () => {}`) attached to dom and they are working correctly?

I know we can test function when we pass as props but looking for help to test default functions. Thanks,

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const LoginForm = ({
  handleChange,
  handleBlur,
  handleSubmit,
}) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    />
    <input
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
    />
    <button type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
);

const shape = { email: '', password: '', generic: '' };

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  handleChange: PropTypes.func,
  handleBlur: PropTypes.func,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
};

LoginForm.defaultProps = {
  handleChange: () => {},
  handleBlur: () => {},
  handleSubmit: () => {},
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to test that the functions have the expected behavior, you can access them as static properties on the LoginForm, and write your tests around that.

```
import LoginForm from 'wherever'

test('should have default handleChange', () => {
   expect(LoginForm.defaultProps.handleChange).toBeDefined();
});

test('something something', () => {
    const result = LoginForm.defaultProps.handleChange();
    expect(result).toBe('something');
});
```

If you want to test that React does what it says it does -- ie, that it will pass the default props in if no other props are specified -- i recommend you don't. The creators of react [have written tests](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/__tests__/ReactJSXElement-test.js#L185) around that.

Answer (score 5):

You can access the props using `mount` and `.props()` from enzyme.

```
import LoginForm from '../somelocation'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'

it('should handleChange when value 'foo' is passed', () => {
   const props = mount(<LoginForm />).props()
   const handleChange = props.handleChange
   expect(handleChange('foo')).to.equal('bar')
 }
```

the const `defaultProps` should give you

```
props = {
   handleChange: () => {},
   handleBlur: () => {},
   handleSubmit: () => {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps.

The answer posted by **@Daniel Varela** is good but could be more clear. Here is how I solved this issue.

I used just what he suggested `mount` and `.props` but the difference is that I wanted to test if some properties and functions were previously defined.

```
// React & Libraries
import React from 'react';    
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
// Features
import ModalConfirmation from './modalConfirmation';

describe('ModalConfirmation', () => {

const wrapper = mount(<ModalConfirmation />);

it('should have default props', () => {
    const props = wrapper.props();
    expect(props).not.be.equal(null);
    expect(props.data).to.deep.equal({});
    expect(props.onCancel).to.not.throw();
    expect(props.onConfirm).to.not.throw();
    expect(props.cancelButtonText.length).be.greaterThan(0);
    expect(props.confirmButtonText.length).be.greaterThan(0);
    expect(props.confirmationMessage).be.equal(null);
});
```

});